# How do I stop a while loop when my countdown timer is up?

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, jupyter-notebook, countdowntimer

```
def timer():
        for t in reversed(range(1, 11)):
            sleep(1)
            print(t)
            if foundAllLetters == True:
                break
            if remaining_attempts == 0:
                break
            if t == 1:
                sleep(1)
                print('TIMES UP!')
    
                
t1 = Thread(target=timer)
t1.start()

while True:
    displayBoard(hang, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)
```

A short context is I am coding a hangman game. What is going my way is that the timer and loop occurs simultaneously. What is not going my way is that I'm unable to stop the loop and restart the game once the timer is up. `gameIsDone = True` <- will restart my hangman game. I can't identify what variable to use with it.

I have tried to put `gameIsDone = True` right under `print('TIMES UP!')` but nothing happened. I have also tried and added `t = 1` in my while loop under else statement, nothing happened.

I am new to python but might have accidentally picked an intermediate activity for my project :\

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'd say move your winning logic to the main part of the code and use `while t1.is_alive():` to check if the user is out of time